# Is it a bug in Selenium documentation?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is the snippet from the new Selenium doc on Waits:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://google.com/ncr");
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("cheese" + Keys.ENTER);
// Initialize and wait till element(link) became clickable - timeout in 10 seconds
WebElement firstResult = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10))
        .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a/h3")));
```

When I paste this code, it gives me an error on the Duration: 
**The constructor WebDriverWait(WebDriver, Duration) is undefined**

It still works with the following syntax:

```
WebElement firstResult = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
                .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a/h3")));
```

Is it the documentation bug?

Comment: Depends on how old the documentation is. You haven't provided a link to the documentation, nor have you told us which version of Selenium you are using.

Comment: It could be obsolete code snippet or you interpreted it improperly.

Comment: Here is the link to the latest official documentation: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/. The Java client version is also the latest - 3.141.59.

Comment: @Vladimir You can see here https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.java that this constructor exists

Comment: @Fenio. Very strange. The latest WebDriver API Doc from the official site https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/index.html does not describe this constructor for WebDriverWait. My code with Java client 3.141.59 does not compile with it.

Comment: @Vladimir I have no answer to your question. You might want to report an issue on GitHub and get the answer there. Also, take a look that in the link I provided constructor `WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, long timeoutInSeconds)` is deprecated. Maybe those sources aren't compiled yet and will be available in Selenium 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in the original question,

```
WebElement firstResult = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
                .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a/h3")));
```

the code above still works. I guess, as @Fenio assumed, the new syntax will be available in Selenium 4 since it exists in the GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

He has no mistake.

```
WebDriverWait wdw = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wdw.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a/h3")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, surely should work:

```java
WebDriverWait w=new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5));
```

`TimeUnit` from the type `WebDriverWait` is deprecated.